# how to change object name dynamically in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
var person1 = {
    firstName : "John",
    lastName  : "Doe",
    age       : 50,
    eyeColor  : "blue"
};
```

lot of object are there like above. 
i have tried get the object like below but not working.

```
var id = "1";

person+id.firstName + " is " + person+id.age + " years old.";
```

please guide me.

Comment: Its not very clear what you are asking, can you explain in more detail?

Comment: Very bad duplicated refferences. I had an example just for your case, but now it's impossible to answer.

Comment: i have javascript objects like person1, person2 ...
each object some properties are there

Comment: get the object name dynamically with concat with number like person+1.fistname but result not came wihtout concat result will coming

Comment: person1.firstName + " is " + person1.age + " years old.";
it is working fine.
my requirement is 
var id = "1";
person+id.firstName; person+id.age; it is not working

Answer (score 1):

If it's in global context then you can get it from `window` object

```js
var person1 = {
  firstName: "John",
  lastName: "Doe",
  age: 50,
  eyeColor: "blue"
};

var id = "1";

document.write(window["person" + id].firstName + " is " + window["person" + id].age + " years old.");
```

Comment: @PrasadBezawada : glad to help